# Remove square bracket from DB2 string and add leading zeros

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm using DB2 11. I have a table employee & it contains one column as employee_id.
It has 114131 records. Out of these records around 20% cases employee_id contains record in this format [12345678] & remaining 80% cases it's in this format 0012345678.So for these 20% cases, I want to remove the square brackets from emp_id and add 2 leading zeros to make it 10 characters long in employee_id column if square bracket is there. Can you please suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Is this Db2 11 on Z/OS or linux/unix/windows?  What is the datatype and length of the employee_id column ?

Comment: @mao,its in windows.Data type is VARGRAPHIC & length of employee_id column is 10. If you can suggest me removal of square bracket then I will add leading zeros

Comment: `regexp_extract(employee_id, '\d+')`  will extract the digits

Comment: Add to pad with leading zeroes, you could use: `lpad(regexp_extract(employee_id, '\d+'),10,'0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this with Db2 v11 on Windows (other ways are possible) is:
`lpad(regexp_extract(employee_id, '\d+'),10,'0')`
so you would use that in a SELECT or UPDATE as appropriate. This would remove any non digit characters, assuming that was the real intent, not only the [ ] .